# PHP Basic Auth in a If that is false is executed

Tags: php, apache, basic-authentication

Basically my main goal is to add a Basic Auth for every url except the ones that starts with "/donation" because i need the bank to reach us at anytime during the dev.

I tried a lot of thing on htaccess but nothing worked (Setting env var by inspecting request_uri etc)

I tried to make it in PHP be something weird happen, here is my code:

```php
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strlen('/donation')) !== '/donation') {
    $AUTH_USER = 'admin';
    $AUTH_PASS = 'admin';
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    $has_supplied_credentials = !(empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']));
    $is_not_authenticated = (
        !$has_supplied_credentials ||
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $AUTH_USER ||
        $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']   != $AUTH_PASS
    );
    if ($is_not_authenticated) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required');
        header('WWW-Text: '. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '"');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Basically i check if Url don't start with /donation and try to basic auth, in my mind the inside code of the if must be not executed on /donation for example but it does...

I tried something simplier for testing :

```php
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strlen('/donation')) !== '/donation') {
    echo "NOT IN DONATION";
    die():
}
```

And this work the die is executing only on anything that don't start with /donation but the first code is always executed on any url i put.

Do you have any idea what is happening here?

Thank you in advance !
Léo

I tried a lot of thing on htaccess but nothing worked (Setting env var by inspecting request_uri etc)

Comment: Since the simple test worked, your URL test must be correct. Add some `var_dump()` calls to the original version to check the values of the other variables you're using in the authentication.

Comment: Did you actually remove the HTTP Auth configuration directives from your .htaccess file? Sounds like that might still be in place, _in addition_ to what you now tried to do in PHP ...